# Setup is Unable to Proceed and when i check .net framework version is 4.8.03761

Tags: 2013, windows-server-2012-r2

I am installing SharePoint 2013 in Windows Server 2012 R2 in a standalone Server, this server is windows update installed, when i install SharePoint 2013 I got below Error

[image]

when i check .Net framework version is 4.8 and i did not found the Kb insalled in Windows Server 2012 r2 Updates history , here how can i fix this error.

PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-Location 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client'
PS HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client> Get-ItemProperty -Path . | Select-Object Version

### Version

4.8.03761

Answer (score 0):

You will need to uninstall 4.8 to clear this error, or install the below patch.

https://www.netwoven.com/2016/11/22/sharepoint-2013-installation-error-in-windows-server-2012-r2-due-to-updated-net-framework-4-5/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/installation-and-setup/setup-error-if-.net-framework-4.6-is-installed

Comment: I didn't bother uninstalling the newer .Net version. I followed the instructions in the Microsoft link under Resolution. Just copy the DLL they provide into the Updates folder with your SharePoint install files.